# On DB Query PHP return NULL but are records

Tags: php, mariadb

[PHP 8.1/SQL 10.4]

**DB Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `trundschreiben` (
  `rsID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rsMTGLemail` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `rsVersendet` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rsVersanddatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rsAbsender` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rssprache` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `rskurse` text COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `rskurseplain` text COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `rsfirmenname` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rstyp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci;
```

**PHP Code:**

```
   $sql = "SELECT MAX(rsID) as rsid FROM trundschreiben";   
   $result = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql);  
   $nrRS =  mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

**GOAL**

Get the highest value of 'rsID' from the table

**WHAT I TRIED**

In phpmyadmin it works perfectly, the value is returned

**QUESTION**

In PHP, `var_dump($nrRS);` returns me a value of

```
array(1) { ["rsid"]=> NULL }
```

while the `$result` returns me this array

```
current_field: 0 
field_count: 1 
lengths: null 
num_rows: 1 
type:0
```

How come I can't receive the value as I expect?
Thank you!

Comment: `PHP returns me a value of null`...where? You haven't shown any attempt to use the contents of `$nrRS` to output anything. What does `var_dump($nrRS);` return?

Comment: @ADyson it's simple null :)

Comment: @ADyson
array(1) { ["rsid"]=> NULL }

Comment: I think that could only happen if the table contains no rows - demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9976769f0f5724191fb5c65436e3a72 . If phpMyAdmin gives you results for the same query, then my guess would be that your PHP code is looking at a different copy of your database.

Answer (score 0):

When your table is empty, the max value is NULL. After inserting at least one row in the table, your code will start returning a number.

[PHP online environment](https://phpize.online/sql/mariadb/6837427bb75bc15de3081759ff0ce996/php/php81/7152ef2fda5b5f94a409efbd9ae6d769/)